# Why is this mysql trigger syntax is wrong?

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

There are two tables involved in this question: Register(eid, sid, price, rating) and Event (eid, ename, edescription, edate, memprice, nonmemprice, maxpeople).

I want to create a trigger that is monitoring the Register that if the number of registrations of any Event exceed the 80% of the maximum people allowed in such event, we arise the non-memberprice of this event by 50%.

So far I have something like this

```
delimiter//
create trigger price_change 
after insert on Register for each row begin
      DECLARE counts INT;
      DECLARE maxpeople INT;
      set counts = (select count(sid) from Register
                   JOIN Event ON Register.eid = Event.eid
                   where eid = new.eid);
      set maxpeople = (select maxpeople from Event where Event.eid = 
                       new.eid);
      if counts >= 0.8 * maxpeople
      then
          update Event set nonmemprice = nonmemprice * 1.5 where eid 
          = new.eid;
      end if;
end//

delimiter;
```

I'm still learning how to write trigger and I ended up with this trigger. I tried to add it into MySQL but it said there are syntax errors basically everywhere of this trigger. I'm really confused. It would be appreciated if anyone help me with this.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details about the error messages you are getting.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya The question is updated. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: `@` should only be used when you want to persist the variable in a particular sessions. You dont need to necessarily use `@` for every variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is right at the beginning. Use a space in between:

```
delimiter //
         ^--------------here
```

<sub>And at the end of course too: `delimiter ;`</sub>

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tips. It does help solving a lot of errors but there is still one left. Would you mind take a look at the latest update of the question again?